# A series of books that came out around 1990 about psychic Native Americans living on another planet

Tags: story-identification

I read a series of books around 1990 that delt with a group of Native Americans that have moved to another planet on the outskirts of known space.  If I remember correctly, they had psychic powers and when they went into battle, they'd scalp their opponents (counting coup).

Comment: I think Futurama spoofed/referenced this in an episode....  [Found it](http://theinfosphere.org/Where_the_Buggalo_Roam).

Comment: @Keen: ["I know it them, cause they no use good gramma."](http://theinfosphere.org/Where_the_Buggalo_Roam#Quotes)

Comment: We're they sent up by competing corporations to scout out planets prior to colonising them? If so I think I have an omnibus with it in. . . Somewhere, I'll have a good 'ol dig for you if this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

The 'Spider' Trilogy by W. Michael Gear.

"[Warriors of Spider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warriors_of_Spider)" followed by the "The Way of Spider" and "The Web of Spider". The Romanan *Prophets* could see the many paths of the future, at the risk of going insane due to the infinite futures.

Comment: Could you say something about why you think this is the correct book?

Comment: Is this better?